# How to access IIS hosted site from another PC

Tags: asp.net, windows, web, iis-7.5

There's this website using IIS 7.5, ASP.NET 4.0.30319 - Windows server

Any ideas on how one can access a website like this remotely? I am used to CMSs and regular websites where you can easily access the back-end anywhere.

Share your thoughts, Please

Comment: You want to access the back-end files on the server?  Remote desktop into the server and there you go.

Comment: Yes, add some content to the website and regular tasks but yes a remote desktop should do the trick right?

Comment: Unless you have the server set up as part of your network, then you can go to the network path in your file explorer and open/edit the files from your machine.

Comment: it's not, I mean an intranet should do the trick as well, I guess, I'll be travelling out of the country, have you worked with websites like this before? hahaha why can't it something like website.com/admin and tada!

Answer (score 0):

You can use iis7 manager. Download: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=2299